# How to get the current camera position latlng in google maps flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, maps

i want to get the current latlng which is centered on the screen. like uber tells name of the place while we are moving the map on the screen it updates the value.

Comment: You may want to check out this [tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/implement-real-time-location-updates-on-google-maps-in-flutter-235c8a09173e) on how to implement real-time location updates on Google Maps in Flutter!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property `onCameraMove` of `GoogleMap` class.

```
GoogleMap(
  onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) {
    print("Latitude: ${position.target.latitude}; Longitude: ${position.target.longitude}");
  },
  [...]
)
```

More info about [GoogleMap](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMap-class.html) and [onCameraMove](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMap/onCameraMove.html).

Answer (score 1):

`onCameraMove` you can get the center location of the screen
and then you can easily use setState to update the value

```
      GoogleMap(
        onCameraMove: (object) => {
          setState(() {
            latitude = object.target.latitude;
            longitude = object.target.longitude;
          })
        },
```

Comment: is there any better way regarding the performance? because using this way can call build() hundreds of times

Comment: @HassanM.Said Wrap setState in a [debounce](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_debounce)